# How to read gitlab variables inside java code?

Tags: java, gitlab

I have defined a variable in my gitlab project named 'APP_PASSWORD'.
Is there a way for me to access this in my java code?
Will System.getEnv("APP_PASSWORD") retrieve the password for me?

Comment: Do you mean during Gitlab CI? Please elaborate.

Comment: yes, in gitlab CI

Comment: In that case your CI variables are ENV variables during your job, so yes, you should be able to retrieve them in your code as you posted.

Comment: Why did you not try before posting here?

Answer (score 0):

CI variables can be used as ENV variables during the build, so retrieving them as you posted should be enough.